# What is the minimum value of $\csc x - \sin x$?

Tags: trigonometry

What is the minimum value of $\csc x - \sin x$? Differentiating and setting it to zero yields nothing meaningful. How can I find the minimum value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no (absolute) minimum if we do not put restrictions on the domain. This is obvious since $\csc x$ is large negative when $x$ is negative and close to $0$. No need of derivatives.

If we restrict the domain to $(0,\pi)$, then differentiation is perhaps warranted. I would set $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sin x}+\sin x$ and differentiate. We get $-\frac{\cos x}{\sin^2 x}+\cos x$, that is, $\frac{\cos x(\sin^2 x-1)}{\sin^2 x}$. This is $0$ at $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$. The top is negative in the interval $(0,\pi/2)$ and positive in $(\pi/2,\pi)$, so we have a minimum at $x=\pi/2$.

There are also non-calculus ways to find the minimum in the interval $(0,\pi)$.

Comment: Ok. Sir had the question being FIND THE MIN VALUE OF 4 cosec^2 x + 9 sin^2 x ? How would you proceed ?

Comment: That's an entirely different problem than the one you asked. There is a non-calculus way, also a calculus way. Which one do you want? The calculus way involves differentiating, it is fairly mechanical. But if you want a full answer, you will need to ask a separate question: writing at length in comments is difficult.

Comment: ok.I will do it seperately.

Answer (score 0):

f(x) = Cosec x - sin x = (1/sin x)-sin x

=(1-sin^2(x))/sin x

= cos^2(x)/sinx=1/(sec x tan x). Will that help?

Note: f(x) is minimised when (sec xtan x) is maximized.

Comment: Yeah so what will the last step. how you maximize the product of sec and tan now ?